# JavaScript: What is the difference between function f(){} and constant f =(function(){...})()?

Tags: javascript, function

Here are two ways of writing a function that includes an IIFE:

```
    function f() {
        let count=0;
        return function() {
            return ++count;
        }
    }

    const g = (function() {
        let count=0;
        return function() {
            return ++count;
        }
    })();
```

f() returns `function () { return ++count; }`

When g() is run several times, it returns 1, 2, 3...  which is the intention.

Now another example:

```
    function f() {
        return "This is f()";
    }

    const g = (function() {
        return "This is g()";
    })();
```

In this case f() returns "This is f()" and g() is a script error.

I've done a lot of coding in C-ish languages, but am new to JavaScript.  What am I missing?

In response to the first answer, here is an executable code snippet.  If `function f(){...}` were the same as `const f = (function () {...})()` I would expect both to run. They do not.

```js
function f() {
    return "This is f()!";
}

console.log(f());

const h = f;

console.log(h());

const g = (function() {
  return "This is g()";
})();

console.log(g());
```

Comment: `g()` is an IIFE. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript. It calls the inner function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in JavaScript are [first class objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function), meaning you can treat them as any other object in JavaScript.

`function f (){}` is regular function definition, which you can also write as

```
let f = function(){}
```

`(function{})()` is basically the same as

```
let f = function () {}
f = f() // You reassign f to be the return value from the function that f was assigned to
```

You bottom case `const g = (function() {return "This is g()";})();` can be written as:

```
let g = function() {
    return "This is g()"
}
g = g() // You are reassigning g to be "This is g()"

// Trying to call g again is like calling a string
// and it should return an error saying that g is not a function
g()
```

### Update

There difference in your extended example is that `f` is a function that returns a function (always), while `g` immediately gets assigned to the inner "regular function", and return numbers.

```
function f() {
    let count = 0;
    // --- Will always return this, a function ----
    return function () {
        return ++count;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------
}

const g = (function () {
    let count = 0;
    return function () {
        return ++count;
    }
})() // <--- Here you call the (function () {}) immediately, thus you assign g to the inner returned function

console.log(f);
console.log(f()); // returns a function
console.log(g); 
console.log(g()); // returns a number
console.log(g());
console.log(g());
console.log(g());
```

To make `f` equivalent to `g` you have to do this:

```
function f() {
    let count = 0;
    return function () {
        return ++count;
    }
}
f = f() // Here
```

Comment: I know `function f(){}`  and let `f = (function{})()` should be the same. But in the example above, `function f(){...}` works.  `const g = (function(){...})();` fails.  Look at the final code snippet added to the question above.

Comment: @JeffHester It is as I said really, you are assigning `g` to a string, and you are attempting to call it: `g()`, if you change `console.log(g())` to `console.log(g)` you will see that are attempting to call the string `"This is ig()"`

Comment: OK...  The simple example was poorly stated. My bad.  But now take a look at the example below.  I understand that I am doubtless being an idiot, but why does `function f() {...iife...}` followed by `f();` fail, while `constant g = (function)() {...exactly the same code...})();  g();` succeed?

Comment: Hmmm... In both cases `const myVar = (function(){...})();` is assigning myVar the value returned when the function executes.  Check.  In the first case f() just returns `function(){return ++count;}` when it is called.  In the second case `(function(){...})` executes immediately, returning the function `function() {return ++count;}`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the following snipped clarifies my question...

And I think I see the answer.  In the first case, f() doesn't do anything until it is called.  And when it is called it returns the string.

In the second case, (function(){})() executes immediately, and returns the function itself.

Like the name says, Immediate execution.  Thanks for helping me ask the right question.

```js
function f() {
        let count=0;
        return function() {
            return ++count;
        }
    }

const g = (function() {
        let count=0;
        return function() {
            return ++count;
        }
    })();
    
 console.log(f);
 console.log(f());
 console.log(g);
 console.log(g());
 console.log(g());
 console.log(g());
 console.log(g());
```

Comment: Hi, I added an update to my answer. I also suggest that you put this snippet in the original  question rather than submitting it as an answer, as it technincally isn't an answer

Comment: I tried to do that in the first place, but it wouldn't let me. I got an error something like "beyond the suggested number of edits".

Comment: Oh ok, that's unfortunate

Comment: Indeed.  And again, thanks. I recognized the problem with the immediate response (which is why they are called "Immediately Invoked Function Expressions" -- duh), then saw your modified answer.  I was missing the obvious thing.  I should probably put "JavaScript is interpreted, not compiled" on my white board in big letters.

Comment: No worries! And take it easy on yourself! Even the best experience moments like this from time to time. I am glad I could help.

Comment: And I'm far from the best. ;-)

Comment: With apologies to whatever ad agency promotes a certain Nevada city...  "What happens in an IFFE stays in the IFFE.  But you can take your winnings home."